# Loop in svelte based on prop

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I was trying to loop through and initialize a dictionary based on a prop in svelte but so far it seems impossible. There's gotta be a way to do this right?

```
<script>
    export let max;
    let map = {};
    $: if(max != undefined){
      for(var i=0; i<max; i++){
        if(i<5) {
          map["id_"+i] = 1;
        }
        else {
          map["id_"+i] = -1;
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<p>{max}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly was the problem of your version (I'd change to `$: if(max) {...}`) (turns out it was using `var` instead of `let`) but if you put the functionality in the [onMount](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount) function it works >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a566c5e974224f9abac99d0f95e754e9?version=3.44.1)

###### App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import Component from './Component.svelte'
</script>

<Component max={20}/>
```

###### Component.svelte

```html
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    export let max;
    let map = {};
    
    onMount(() => {         
      for(var i=0; i<max; i++){
        if(i<5) {
          map["id_"+i] = 1;
        }
        else {
          map["id_"+i] = -1;
        }
      }
    console.log(map)
    })

</script>

<p>{max}</p>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. Also after looking at it some more, I suspect my original code will work if the `var i = 0` becomes a `let i = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Corrl's version works, but has an important caveat: your array won't be updated if you change the max prop on the fly, because the component will not be destroyed & re-mounted, and hence your array routine will not run again.

Perhaps this is your intent, or perhaps it is not.

A reactive version *will* keep the array updated. However, when dealing with reactive statements, my advice is always to keep these statements as simple as possible.

A cleaner solution to your problem would be to move your array building routine into a simple function that accepts the `max` value as input and returns the initialized array:

```js
function makeMap(max) {
  const map = {}
  for(var i=0; i<max; i++){
    if (i<5) {
      map["id_"+i] = 1
    } else {
      map["id_"+i] = -1
    }
  }
  return map
}
```

Then your reactive code becomes a very simple:

```js
$: map = makeMap(max)
```

that respects the fundamental reactive assignment rule with the reactive variable (`map`) on the left hand side and the dependency (`max`) on the right hand side.

[Here is a REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/38b27af4911f4a7f8a6b44dcb80ec893?version=3.44.1) demonstrating the difference between having your array updated through a reactive statement, and having it initialized through `onMount`. Have a look at the console while you change the `max` prop passed to the component by clicking on the `+` button.